# Restricting a custom group of people from accessing a page

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I have a Team site in which I have 3 pages and 3 custom permission groups as example Level 1, Level 2 and Level 3. What I am required to do is Level 3 can access page 1, 2 and 3 whereas Level 2 can access page 1 and 2 but not 3. Lastly Level 1 can only access page 1 and not 2 or 3.

I created custom permission groups but I cannot see them in Manage Access of those Site Pages.

Is there a way I can limit access of Level 1 to pages 2 and 3 as it contains some information that Level 2 and 3 should not be able to see?

Thank you in advance.